# Does Laravel autogenerates autoload files without runninq composer by user?

Tags: laravel, composer-php

A strange thing happened on my server:
autoload files in `vendor/composer` directory were touched/regenerated without me or any other user running `composer install`, `composer update`, `composer dump-autoload` or any other commands. My main concern is that one of the files was generated with invalid data that crashed my whole site and it took a time to find the problem.

Are there any circumstances that Laravel does this automatically? (There may have been a network malfunction for a few minutes when this happened.) If yes, where can I read about this in the documentation? Is it possible to turn it off?

Comment: how are you deploying your code?

Comment: What is your laravel version ? we had a `php artisan dump-autoload`  command in old versions. maybe you have a library that using this command ( if you have an old Laravel version too )

Comment: I upload my files via ftp (I was not granted ssh and terminal on the hosting system). It is Laravel 5.4, and the solution was that I regenerated the autoload files locally (with `composer dump-autoload`) and uploaded them to the server. I will give a look at the libraries.